# "aber auch erst"-meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is an excerpt from one of the Goethe Zertifikat mock tests:

> Vielleicht kann ich am Morgen wieder zum Arbeit kommen. Vielleicht aber auch erst am Montag.

What exactly is "auch" of the second sentence for? Although I do understand the overall meaning of the sentence.

Comment: It must be *zur Arbeit* and should be *morgen* instead of *am Morgen*.

Comment: @Janka: If "now" is e.g. Thursday evening it might be "am Morgen" (that is, say, Friday, 8:00 o'clock) or Monday, at some arbitrary time, whereas "morgen" would mean Friday, at some arbitrary tme.

Answer (score 3):

"It is *also* possible that I cannot return before Monday."